# Listview item is not aligned properly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have created on chat screen and i want to display sent message on left side and received messages right side.
To do this i have created two xml one for right and one for left and i have bind this two xml with adapter.
The problem is that when i am sending a text it resides on left side and when i am receiving a text,the sent text is also aligned on right side.and when i am sending again then whole text(chat) aligns on left.

**Here is my ArrayAdapter:**

```
private void setListAdapterL() {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterL = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.row_left, messages);
    mList.setAdapter(adapterL);
}

private void setListAdapterR() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterR = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.row_right, messages);
    mList.setAdapter(adapterR);
}
```

**My xml** file for **row_right.xml**.in other **row_left.xml** just gravity is changed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip" />
```

Any ideas and suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Show us your screen for listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you have to create custom adapter for list view instead of creating two separate adapters for left item (i.e., sent item) and right item (i.e., received item).

It means you have manage sent/received messages in one custom adapter.

for e.g.

```
// Sample messages inside MessageActivity
void initMessages() {
  HashMap<String, String> messageSent = new HashMap<String, String>();
  messageSent.put("message", "Hi");
  messageSent.put("type", "sent");
  messageSent.put("date", "");

  HashMap<String, String> messageReceived = new HashMap<String, String>();
  messageSent.put("message", "Hello");
  messageSent.put("type", "received");
  messageSent.put("date", "");

  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> messages = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
  messages.add(messageSent);
  messages.add(messageReceived);

  MessageAdapter adapter = new MessageAdapter(mContext, messages);
  setListAdapter(apater);
}

// adapter class
class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MessageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
        super(context, R.layout.raw_message, data);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_message, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtSent = convertView.findViewByTag("sent");
            holder.txtReceived = convertView.findViewByTag("received");
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        HashMap<String,String> message = getItem(position);
        boolean sent = message.get("type").equals("sent");

        if(sent) {
            holder.txtSent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.txtSent.setText(message.get("message"));
            holder.txtReceived.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.txtSent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.txtReceived.setText(message.get("message"));
            holder.txtReceived.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);     
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtSent;
        TextView txtReceived;
    }
}

// raw_message.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="sent"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="received"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that when i am sending a text it resides on left side and when i am receiving a text,the sent text is also aligned on right side.and when i am sending again then whole text(chat) aligns on left.

That is probably happening because each time you get a new message you set a new adapter for the `ListView` with the new gravity(left or right). Because the new adapter holds **all** messages in the chat they all get aligned left or right.

My advice is to use a data object class that will hold the actual message + its status(it's a received or sent message):

```
class Message {
    String actualMessage;
    int status = 0; //(for example 0 for sent messages and 1 for received messages)

    public String toString() {
       return actualMessage;
    }
}
```

Then implement your own adapter and in the `getView` method see which type of message do you have and set the orientation for that particular row to left or right. This will also allow you to just update the list of messages instead of creating each time a new `ArrayAdapter` object. Adapter example:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {

     public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resId, List<message> data) {
          super(context, resId, data);
     }

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         TextView tv = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
         Message msg = getItem(position);
         if (msg.status == 0) {
               tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
         } else {
               tv.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
         } 
     }

}
```

Comment: in above class how to determine a status of message because from where that status is passed is not mentioned?

Comment: @juned I don't know your code to tell you exactly but all you have to do is instead of calling either the method `setListAdapterL` or `setListAdapterR` construct a `Message` object with either `obj.status = 0;`(if you would normally call `setListAdapterL`) or with `obj.status = 1;`(if you would normally call `setListAdapterR`) and add it to the adapter(maybe also call `notifydataSetChanged`).

Answer (score 0):

you're facing the problem that ALL you're items always get changed to the new layout. So everytime you're setting the left layout everything moves to the left side vice versa.

What you need is a [custom adapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List4.html) which enables you to have 2 textviews - one for the right side and one for the left one.